# JQuery - Hide and Show - Not Functioning

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I am trying to use the JQuery Hide and show script to display text on top an image when the div tag is clicked.

The JQuery code I am using is bellow, I have created a JSFiddle to show 2 examples, a before and after with my current result.

- UPDATE: I have managed to get the toggle to work and changed some of the CSS. But need div tag hidden until click.

Any help or feedback would be great thanks (Y)

Im sorry about the prev link;

```
$(".card-options").click(function () {
$(".card-list").toggle();
});
```

[JSfiddle][1]

[1] http://jsfiddle.net/jinghming/u4epkev4/

Comment: I'm not clicking on that link. Please post a normal fiddle, not a collaboration.

Comment: Or better yet, use SO's built-in stack snippet feature to put the code directly in the question.

Comment: I made the mistake of clicking the link. The fiddle has some weird overlay stuff spanning all frames. Barmar's right - don't click it.

Comment: Some really weird collaboration tool, never seen that before. Don't click the fiddle link people.

Comment: @Giannis Sorry Here you go http://jsfiddle.net/jinghming/u4epkev4/

Comment: @Barmar sorry about that prev link heres one without the collab tool http://jsfiddle.net/jinghming/u4epkev4/

Comment: @Roamer-1888 My apologies about that link, first time using jsfiddle accidentally clicked collab. heres an updated link http://jsfiddle.net/jinghming/u4epkev4/

Answer (score 0):

Instead Of using

```
$("#div").click(function(){
$(".box").hide();
});

$("#div").click(function(){
$(".box").show();
```

});

I used toggle function;

```
$("#div").click(function () {
$(".box").toggle();
});
```

*Still working out how to have .box hidden until #div is clicked. But currently does switch between hide and show.

Comment: To have div hidden first, I set css property for div to display:none.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, when the little black box is clicked, the list should appear and disappear - I can't see the link to your updated fiddle so here is the update I made to your JS:

```
$(".card .card-options").click(function () {
    $(this).parents('.card').find('.card-list').toggleClass('active');
});
```

I've also added a `display: none;` to your `.card-list` CSS declaration and added the following:

```
.card-list.active {display: block;}
```

If you want that bottom bar to be at the bottom of the box then you'd have to do some absolute positioning.

See the updated fiddle here:
http://jsfiddle.net/u4epkev4/4/

Answer (score 0):

You just need to do toggle and you forgot to go into `card-text`:

```
$(".card-list").hide(); // Hides the card list at the start
$(".card .card-text .card-options").click(function () {
    // Toggle the card-list for the clicked card
    $(this).parent().parent().find(".card-list").toggle();
});
```

**[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/u4epkev4/6/)**